# PHP - File Get Contents - Setting Maximum Length

Tags: php, file-get-contents, maxlength

I am trying to get the contents of a web page up to the 100th character. However, for some reason the code isn't getting the web page at ALL.

Here's my code:

```
$link = "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=1";
echo file_get_contents($link, NULL, NULL, -1, 100);
```

The reason I am wanting to do this is to get the title of that web page. I cannot figure out why it won't display. Probably the 3rd argument, which I've tried making an alternative for:

```
$opts = array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET",'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" ."Cookie: foo=bar\r\n");
```

Even with the above variable set for the 3rd argument it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: look at the source code.. it's getting the doctype part of your target.

Comment: Yeah I noticed, however it won't even give me the doctype element. It's giving me null.

Comment: if I assign the `file_get_contents` part to a variable and `var_dump` it it's displaying the doctype string. def not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$link = "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=1";
var_dump(file_get_contents($link, NULL, NULL, 0, 100));
```

Output

```
string '



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/' (length=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

use  this

```
echo substr(file_get_contents($link),0,100);
```

Comment: That's the thing. I am using this function a lot and trying to reduce bandwidth so it doesn't do me any good. I think I know what's wrong, however.

Comment: thanks though... it'd work if I wasn't wanting to use it for bandwidth. +1